# Find top 10 students mark using array of object

Tags: arrays, sorting

I recently had an interview,they asked me a small question
the question is follows

There is list of Students

```
    List<Student> students;

    Class Student{
     String rollNo;
     Map<String, Integer> marks ;
}
```

Stdunt.marks is actually cobination of subject and mark

Should write an method which should return top 10 students array according to the subject.

```
List<Student> getTop10(String subjectName){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer i have given is blelow

```
private static void PrintTop5(ArrayList<Student> list,String subject){
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Student>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Student st1, Student st2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return  st2.getSubjectMark(subject) - st1.getSubjectMark(subject);
        }
    });

    ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>(list.subList(0,5));
    for(Student student : studentList){
        System.out.println(student.getRollNum() + " MARK : "+student.getSubjectMark(subject));
    }
}
```

Student class look like below

```
package com.main;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class Student {

    private String rollNo;
    private HashMap<String, Integer> marks ;

    public Student(){
        marks = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void setRollNumber(String number){
        this.rollNo = number;
    }

    public void setSubjectAndMark(String subName,int mark){
        this.marks.put(subName, mark);
    }

    public HashMap<String, Integer> getAllMarks(){
        return marks;
    }

    public int getSubjectMark(String subject){
        return marks.get(subject);
    }

    public String getRollNum(){
        return rollNo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general your idea is correct, to sort the entire list and take top N students, in fact with java 8 it would look cleaner.

```
private static void PrintTop5(ArrayList<Student> list,String subject){
    list.sort(Comparator
                    .comparing((Student student) -> student.getSubjectMark(subject))
                    .reversed());

    List<Student> studentList = list.stream().limit(5).collect(Collectors.toList());
    for(Student student : studentList){
        System.out.println(student.getRollNum() + " MARK : "+student.getSubjectMark(subject));
    }
}
```